# Find longer side of a rectangle with respect to another rectangle

Tags: geometry, graphing-functions, area, algebraic-graph-theory, rectangles

So I have two rectangles:

```
Rectangle R1 with width r1w and height r1h
Rectangle R2 with width r2w and height r2h
```

I can find the slope/aspect ratio of the two rectangles using:

```
r1Slope = r1h/r1w
r2Slope = r2h/r2w
```

Now what I want is this: ONLY using the `r1Slope` and `r2Slope` values I want to see which is the longer side in R1 with respect to R2.

Example, Lets say:

```
R1 Width  (r1w) = 2000
R1 Height (r1h) = 1000

R2 Width  (r2w) = 400
R2 Height (r2h) = 150
```

I also can calculate the slopes as:

```
r1Slope = (1000/2000) = 0.5
r2Slope = (150/400) = 0.38
```

So is there a way I can formalize a `comparison/calculation` on `r1Slope and r2Slope` in order to find whether it is `r1w or r1h` that is the longer side? (I think in this case it is `r1h`)

As you might have deduced math really is not my forte, so I am hoping someone will advise me in the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you meant to compare $\frac{r1h}{r2h}$ and $\frac{r1w}{r2w}$, then it is correct. Because whether $\frac{r1h}{r2h}>\frac{r1w}{r2w}$ is equivalent to whether $\frac{r1h}{r1w}>\frac{r2h}{r2w}$ which is the comparison between your slopes.